# Eclipse Java error: This selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches

Tags: java, eclipse

I have looked everywhere on the internet and tried everything the forums say to do and nothing works.
This error keeps coming up. I have tried running my java project (not for android) even the drop down run as button doesn't work because it says "none applicable".

Comment: can you post up your code that is troubling you?

Comment: Right-click on the main class and select run there.

Comment: @KickButtowski I don't think the problem is in his code, but rather, the way he's trying to run the project. Right-click on source file > Run As > Java Application should do it.

Comment: There is no code in my file, just the normal class()

Comment: how would @chrylis I? it just says run as> rum configuration

Comment: @MarsAtomic it says (none applicable) after run as

Comment: @MarsAtomic i clicked on my src file but it says i dont have a main?

Comment: How did you get the project into Eclipse? Did you write it in the IDE or did you try to import it somehow? And check all of your source files to make sure at least one of them has "public static void main(String[] args) in it.

Comment: I had to delete my old projects (eclipse was running before) and made a new workbench like when you first open eclipse. After i just hit file>new java project then i made a java class inside it as i did in my school @MarsAtomic i have my public static void main(String[]args)

Comment: JUST FIGURED IT OUT THANK YOU ALL it was my main that was messed up then i ran it from the src file as told. @MarsAtomic can i put you as the person that answered my question?

Answer (score 60):

Eclipse needs to see a main method in one of your project's source files in order to determine what kind of project it is so that it can offer the proper run options:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Without that method signature (or with a malformed version of that method signature), the Run As menu item will not present any run options.

Comment: Now yes, everything works - Thanks ➡

Answer (score 19):

Check, you might have written this statement wrong.

```
public static void main(String Args[])
```

I have also just started java and was facing the same error and it was occuring as i didn't put `[]` after args.
so check ur statment.

Answer (score 8):

Click on the drop down next to the Run button, After that choose Run Configuration, shows three option, for example i choose java application add class(Name of the class of your project) in that then Click on the ok button ...Run your application :)

Neeraj

Answer (score 5):

When you create a new class file, try to mark the check box near

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

this will help you to fix the problem.

Answer (score 5):

click on the project that you want to run on the left side in package explorer and then click the Run button.

Comment: Thats is Correct.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the "m" in main() is lowercase this would also cause java not to see your main method, I've done that several times unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

It happens when sometimes we copy or import the project from somewhere. The source folder is a big thing to concern about.

One simple technique is, create a new project, inside the source folder, create a new class and paste the content over there.

It will work...

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the filename is same as the classname used by your program.

eg.:

```
class Dfs{ psvm(String[] args){}}
```

filename should be Dfs.java

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if:

1. You created a `class` file under `src` folder in your JAVA project?(not `file`)
2. Did you name your class as the same name of your class file?

I am a newbie who try to run a helloworld example and just got the same error as yours, and these work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check there might be build error in problem message view.

Answer (score 0):

If you have imported the project into STS then just open up your main class - if you don't have one, create one - by double clicking.

Then try running the project again.